# Show that a set is countable by specifying an alphabet for it

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability, formal-languages

Consider the set $S = \{ \sqrt n \mid n \in \Bbb N_0\}$

This is a countable set certainly as we can produce a simple one-to-one function for this set to natural numbers. But I want to do it another way. There is a theorem that given an alphabet set the language generated over that alphabet is countable. So for using this theorem, I have to come up with an alphabet for $S$

Comment: What is an alphabet for a set of numbers? $S$ isn't a language, after all.

Comment: For a set of numbers the alphabet would be {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: What's wrong with $\Sigma=\{\sqrt{},0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?

Comment: yeah. Looks perfect.